# sp_addrolemember with WHERE clause - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to add a WHERE clause within the sp_addrolemember script so that I don't have to create the stored procedure in every single database?

For example in my stored procedure:

```
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL            NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @GrantSql       INT

    EXEC @GrantSql = sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', @LoginName WHERE DatabaseName = 'DBName'

    IF @GrantSQL = 0

        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO TableName....

        END
END
```

Comment: WHERE is used for *filtering*, not specifying a target database

Comment: Great Scott… I would advise against adding an arbitrary user into the `db_owner` role. But that's just how *I* like to party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In documentation:

> Adds a database user, database role, Windows login, or Windows group
>   to a database role in the **CURRENT** database

But you can try:

```
EXEC @GrantSql = DBName..sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', @LoginName
```

If `DBName` is a parameter, you should use parametrized dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) =
N'EXEC @GrantSql = ' + QUOTENAME(@DBName) + '..sp_addrolemember @RoleName, @LoginName'

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql, N'@RoleName NVARCHAR(MAX), @LoginName NVARCHAR(255)', @RoleName, @LoginName
```

P.S.
Here is a good article about dynamic sql:
http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

I think everyone who are about to write dynamic sql **MUST** read it

Comment: Yes the DBName will be a parameter

Comment: I've added dynamic sql